# How do I count this?

Tags: sheet-music

[image]

I'm teaching myself to read music and I'm struggling how to count each top bar. It just keeps on being more than 3:( Any help would be much appreciated.:)

Comment: "One and two and three and one and two and three and..." isn't working for you? The rhythm in the treble clef would be (bold words indicate new notes): "**One** and two **and three** and **one** and to **and three** and..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of the three beats as counted 1,2,3. Then the subdivisions can be counted as 1 & 2 & 3 &. So the dotted quarter takes up 1 & 2; then the eighth note the next & and the last quarter note as 3.(Quarter note = Crochet, Eighth note = Quaver) Actually, any short syllable can be used instead of "and."

The 3/4 means three main pulses; each pulse can have subdivisions or even have irregular connections between the notes.